# Why this python code occurs the side-effect?

Tags: python, list, side-effects

```
def to_un(g):
    un = []
    for v in g:
        un.append(v)
    print(g)
    for v in range(len(un)):
        for u in un[v]:
            if v not in un[u]:
                un[u].append(v)
    print(g)
    print(g == un)
    print(g is un)

def main():
    a = [[1], []]
    to_un(a)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

result:

```
[[1], []]
[[1], [0]]
True
False
```

I expected that the value of g should not changed but it actually changed.
I don't know what side-effect was occurred in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`un` is a shallow copy of `g`, so the nested lists are references to the same lists in both. You need to copy the nested lists as well.

```
un = [v[:] for v in g]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of lists in python being passed by reference. In this case, the elements of `g` are lists, which means when you do:

```
un = []
for v in g:
    un.append(v)
```

You're copy the references of each list `v`, to `un`. This means if you change the elements of `un`, you'll change the elements of `g`. To avoid this, replace the above lines with:

```
import copy
un = copy.deepcopy(g)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to 'Pass by reference' in list in python. You can achieve the results you need by doing just this:
**un[:] = g**
Instead of
un = []
for v in g:
   un.append(v)

Comment: This is due to 'Pass by reference' in list in python. You can achieve the results you need by doing just this: un[:] = g Instead of un = [] for v in g: un.append(v)